# Estimate mean from sample data

Tags: mean, sample

Assuming a sufficiently large set of data, is there a formula for "predicting" a mean value with a certain degree of accuracy without calculating the mean for the whole set of data?

Example, say I have a million data points of whole numbers between 100 and 900. Is there a way to predict the mean +- 5 points with a smaller subset of the data (say 10,000 data points)?

I'm a sw dev not a stats person, but have been asked to report on a rough average, and our existing tools are having trouble with processing the whole data set.

Edit:
By tooling, I'm referring to our cassandra DB where the data is stored.  I do not have the ability to install Spark or another analytics platform, and the inbuilt aggregation queries are failing with data sets much smaller than 1 million records.

Comment: Just a comment: "sufficiently large" is superfluous.  It's easy to estimate the mean of a small population--just compute it!  The upshot is that you are asking how to estimate the mean of *any* population to within a stated error.  To do so without a direct computation, you have to risk getting the answer wrong.  This risk is usually expressed as the chance you will get it right--that is, that your estimate will be correct to within the stated accuracy.  This chance is called the *confidence level.*  BTW, why are there any problems processing a set of a million numbers?

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the feedback.  Like I said, not a stats person.  I thought that this might be a confidence level computation, but didn't know if I could get that without knowing the std deviation. Our data set is actually significantly larger than a million (closer to 250), I used that thinking a "round" number might make the computation easier.  The problems with computation, I assume, are coming from our available tooling.  See edit for these details.